# C++ reverse vectors TL engine

Tags: c++, vector-graphics

I have been having some trouble reversing my vectors in my game when a collision occurs what I need to do is flip the value to the inverse of the current value each time a marble hits an object. The vectors are directions that I need to reverse to make the bounce of look realistic.

Comment: Multiply vector with -1?

Comment: I have done this for the X, Y and Z movement but currently it bounces into the floor.

Comment: Could it be that the marbles are supposed to bounce of the wall rather than just reverse direction?

Comment: By reversing the X, Y, Z direction vectors it has the affect like it bouncing of the wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you're talking about is a vector in the mathematical sense, rather than the container. Let's still assume that you've implemented it with an `std::vector<fieldT>` where e.g. `typedef double fieldT`. You seem to want to have the direction reflected by some obstacle. It's easy when the "mirror" lies in direction of one of your basis vector, then you only need to negate that component – a "mirror" in the *xy*-plane (in 3D) would do

```
v[2] = -v[2];
```

i.e. flip the *z*-component, in the *yz*-plane it would be

```
v[0] = -v[0];
```

It gets more complicated if the reflections occur in arbitrary direction. One possibility is to determine the speed component in direction of the plane – that's done by calculating the scalar product between the speed vector and the normal vector of the plane – and then substracting twice the normal vector, weighted with that factor.

```
std::vector<fieldT> n   // normal vector of the plane
                  , v   // speed vector
                  ;

fieldT eta=0;
for (unsigned i=0; i<n.size(); ++i)     //scalar product between v and n
  eta += v[i]*n[i];
for (unsigned i=0; i<n.size(); ++i)     //substract twice the weighted normal vector
  v[i] -= 2*eta*n[i];
```

A more general approach would be modelling the reflection by matrix application: a reflection is essentially application of an orthogonal linear mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code for calculating a deflection off of a flat and rigid surface.

`CurrentVelocity` is the velocity of the object that will be deflected off of a surface.
`CollisionNormal` is the vector that represents the normal of the surface doing the deflecting.
The code below returns the new velocity assuming an instant deflection.

```
Vector3 CalculateDeflection(const Vector3& CurrentVelocity, const Vector3& CollisionNormal)
{
    Vector3 newVelocity = (-2 * Vector3.Dot(CurrentVelocity, CollisionNormal) * CollisionNormal + CurrentVelocity);

    return newVelocity;
}

float Vector3::Dot(const Vector3& lhs, const Vector3& rhs)
{
    return ((lhs.X * rhs.X) + (lhs.Y * rhs.Y) + (lhs.Z * rhs.Z));
}
```